# Datatables Datetime Extract Minutes and Add CSS Class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatable

Using Datatables v1.10

Currently my table displays a date in the second column in this format `17-04-2019 14:34`. This is the format returned by the database. Everything works as expected, filtering and searching.

The HTML table cell currently looks like this;

> `<td class="sorting_1">17-04-2019 14:34</td>`

I want to select the **minutes** in each cell and add a custom css class around them, something like this

> `<td class="sorting_1">17-04-2019 <span class="text-muted">14:34</span></td>`

My datatables code is below;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable({
    "columns": [
      {
        data: 'date',
        "render": function(data, type, row) {
          return data;
          // console.log(data) displays a string 
          // in this format 17-04-2019 14:34
        },
      }
    ],
  });
});
```

I've tried using the JavaScript String split() method but can't get it to work.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable({
    "columns": [
      {
        data: 'date',
        "render": function(data, type, row) {
          var array = row['datePaid'].split(" ");
          var date = array[0];
          var mins = array[1];
          data = date + ' ' + '<span class="text-muted">' + mins + '</span>';
          return data;
          // console.log(data) displays a string 
          // in this format 17-04-2019 14:34
        },
      }
    ],
  });
});
```

I'm sure there are more efficient ways of doing this but it should work.

Answer (score 1):

`split()` would work for this. You can then output the second item in the resulting array after wrapping it in the `span`, something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable({
    "columns": [{
      data: 'date',
      render: function(data, type, row) {
        var d = data.split(' ');
        return `${d[0]} <span class="text-muted">${d[1]}</span>`;
      },
    }],
  });
});
```

Another alternative would be to use a Regex:

```
render: function(data, type, row) {
  return data.replace(/^([\d-]+)\s([\d:])+$/, '$1 <span class="text-muted">$2</span>')
},
```